# Odoo POS session with more than 6000 enteries not closing

Tags: session, odoo, odoo-10, point-of-sale

One of my clients did not close POS session for 1 year, due to some accounting issues, now it has more than 6000 pos orders and they want to close it.
I have tried to close and it took more than 12 hours and yet could not reconcile all entries and throw a time-out exception.

Is there a way to close the session manually, automatically, or using code or database queries?
Any help will be highly appreciated.
Thank you.

*Note odoo version 10.